# Unknown Error when sending post request from angular6 to nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to send a simple post request using httpClient (from angular front-end) to a nodeJS express server,
from some reason i keep getting a "Unknown Error" when trying to do so,

the code I am using in the front-end:

```
 this.httpClient.post('http://127.0.0.1:8989/login',
      { username:  'test',
        password:  'pass1'
      }, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } })
      .subscribe(
        data  => {
          debugger;
          console.log('POST Request is successful', data);
        },
        error  => {
          console.log('ERROR');
        }
      );
```

The code i am using in the nodejs express backend:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', true)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
app.listen('8989');
console.log('Server started! At http://127.0.0.1:8989');
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var ip = req.ip || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log('***** ' + user + " " + password + " " + ip);
});
```

and the error i get in the client when request is sent:

> "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8989/login: 0 Unknown
>   Error"

any ideas? i suspected the CORS but nothing i added to the headers changed the end result - I kept getting this non informative error

Comment: Can you hit that endpoint through postman/paw or some other HTTP client?  Add some more logging to your server.  What is the server logs say?  If you think it is a CORS issue, check out https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: the cors installation using npm did the trick! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with your response in that you can't set headers with

```
res.headers("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

you need to call

```
res.setHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

If you are working with express, I would suggest using https://github.com/expressjs/cors for dealing with CORS issues.